# How to keep large sets of data in memory in a windows form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, datatable

I am currently storing about a million rows into a DataTable,
this takes about 600 Mb RAM.

So, when you run the application it with store a 1 000 000 rows in a DataTable and display that on a GridView. When you close the Application this will obviously clear the memory.

I will Like to give the user this option, in other words when the user tries to close the form  he will be asked whether he wants to clear memory or not.

The reason for doing this is that does not have to wait for the data to be read into the Datatable each time he runs the application.

.... I am fairly new to C#, so I apologize if this is an in appropriate question here.

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense as it's worded: how will you keep your data in memory if the application is closed?  Do you mean that you want to store the data to disk?

Comment: I do not want to destroy the DataTable that I have created when the application started, this must be  the users decision to remove the DataTable from memory.

Comment: If the application is shut down, you *cannot* keep the DataTable in memory.  It will not be there when your application starts unless you load it!

Comment: Yes, That I know, I thought there might be a "easy" way of doing this in  C#,without creating window services, or writing to the disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only keep something in memory if there is a running application / process with that data in memory - if your application closes (and there is only 1 instance of your application open with that data in memory) then the memory will be released.  If you want to keep it in memory then your only options would be

- Don't close your application, e.g. just hide the window instead (generally a very bad idea that your users won't thank you for)
- Keep that data in another separate process that stays running even when your application isn't, for example a Windows service (again possibly not something that your users are going to thank you for, unless you are actually trying to develop a form of service as opposed to a Windows application).

A much better idea would be change the way your application works with large data sets so that it doesn't need to keep it all in memory, for example if you display all of that data in a large list view then use a virtual list view so that only those rows currently being displayed to the user are loaded into memory.  You can then store your data either in an external database or a semi-permanent file (such as a SQLite database).

Or just load the data set each time like you currently are.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you keep it in a file or database instead of in memory. You can query some data that you want to use during runtime. For instance, 20 or 50 records at a time.

It does not make sense if you display 1M records in datagrid at once and I bet that even you will not look through them.

Comment: I am just stress-testing the application, I duplicated a table with 14000 rows. The data comes from a Database and I store this into a DataTable, since it takes longer to query a Database then the Datatable. So I do not want the data on disk or a database, but in memory, something like the way Qlikview works.

Comment: I suggested you load data just 20 to 50 records at a time because this make the application more responsive and user is more likely to look through all data you load. If you search something on Google and it shows 10,000 results per page, how long it gonna take and how many results you are going to look into?

Comment: Sorry I was a bit slow to get it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try compressing a particular region of data(set of objects corresponds to rows) and extract when needed.
Refer,
[Compressing Object in Dot Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092309/compressing-object-in-dot-net)